# Add jquery-generated <section> for container around two jquery-generated divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm very new to coding so I'm probably missing something simple. I believe I need to create a "container" section around two jquery-generated sections so I can add a border to the entire "card" created by the sections being side-by-side. I have the two sections being created under my "container" in the correct order and together (so one employee's data stays together), but ALL the sections are created under one container.

I tried using "wrap" and "wrapAll" and I tried to create the container div first via jquery but the two template sections continue to fall under a single container div. I was trying to use inline-block for the two sections instead of a container but I need to put a border around each card (made up of the two sections side-by-side). If there is a way to do that without each being wrapped in a container I'm all ears.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Creating the container for the flex item -->
    <section class="container"></section>
</body>
```

JS ("employee" is a table with details like job title, company, etc.)

```
let employeeHTML = employee.map(function(el){

 let details = `
 <section class="intro">
   //creating <article> and <p> for data in section
   </section>`;

   $(".container").append(details);

// });

// let detailsHTML = employee.map(function(el){
 let introDetails = `
 <section class="intro-details">
   //creating multiple <article> and <p> for data in section
   </section>`;

   $(".container").append(introDetails);
});
```

What I'm getting is:

```
<section class="container">
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
</section>
```

But what I want is:

```
    <section class="container">
      <section class="intro></section>
      <section class="intro-details"></section>
    </section>

<section class="container">
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
</section>

<section class="container">
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
</section>
```

Unless there is a better way to put a border on the screen around each pair once side-by-side:

```
  <section class="intro></section>
  <section class="intro-details"></section>
```

Comment: So rather than appending to the existing container, you need to make a new one each time, append to that, and then at the end append that new container to the body

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I changed from what you suggested is I added a "newcontainer" under the <section container> I already had. Mainly because I wasn't sure how to add a new container to the body this way ;o)

Comment: `$(document.body).append(<newthing>)`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!